# Best alternative for scoped enums - Pre C++11

Tags: c++, enums, c-preprocessor

I'd like to start using enums in a few places within my code, but I have an issue with previous declarations from the compiler. How the enums are currently declared makes the most sense to me:

What's the best way to avoid a situation like this?

```
enum score_methods_t {NONE,ABS_FROM_PERFECT,ERROR_SQUARED};
enum scale_methods_t {NONE,CASES_MULTIPLIER,RANGE_MULTIPLIER};
```

Should I just make everything unique, or scope with namespace? I'd like to use the enum types within a class and NONE is the most descriptive name!

Also is the reason the enums clash is because essentially thay are just #defines under the hood??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In pre-C++11 times, I used:

```
struct score_methods { enum type { NONE, ABS_FROM_PERFECT, ERROR_SQUARED }; };
```

which means you always have `score_methods::type` for the actual `enum` type and `score_methods::NONE`, etc. for the values.

Also, no, they are not just `#define`s as you can put them into different namespaces or classes (as seen above) and that is something the preprocessor can not do/handle.

Comment: Using this approach, how do you declare variables, class members, function arguments of the enum type?

Comment: @ulidtko Using `::type`, as in `score_methods::type`. That's the price you pay in pre-C++11. :)

Comment: Yeah... Can we declare a `score_methods::value` member, of the same enum type, and make some use of the implicit struct assignment operator? That looks way more type-safe to me.

Comment: @ulidtko My personal experience was that the above (what I put into the answer) is helpful, anything else adds too much complexity (if you really want to get it right) and is not worth the effort. The real solution is C++11's `enum class`, if emulating most of it (mostly the type-safety part) in pre-C++11 would be easy, the committee wouldn't have extended the language :)

Answer (score 5):

You can always put the enums in a class:

```
struct Score
{
     enum Method { None, AbsFromPerfect, ErrorSquared };
};
```

Usage:

```
void foo(Score::Method m);

foo(Score::None);
```

Comment: This isn't as typesafe as `enum class`, right? I.e. type errors like `foo(15)` would typecheck and compile just fine.

Comment: @ulidtko: No, [that wouldn't compile](http://ideone.com/6wWorj) because of the usual conversion rules for enums.

Answer (score 0):

I find when I use bit-wise unscoped enumerations I get the benefit of automatic conversion to int while still being able to refer to a bit as, e.g., IoType::Input given:

```
enum IoType
    {
    Indeterminable = 0,
    Input          = 1,
    Output         = 2,
    IOput          = Input|Output,
    };
```